Нужно ли тире после "вынужден быть"
Уточните, пожалуйста, уместно ли тире в данном случае?

Он всегда мечтал быть музыкантом. Вынужден быть — помощником отца.

С одной стороны оно кажется уместным, а с другой, не могу объяснить почему.
Спасибо.

Я бы записала так:
Он всегда мечтАл быть музыкантом. Но был вЫнужден стать — помощником отца.
Пояснение
Здесь нужно правильно выбрать форму глагола. Был вынужден — действие закончилось до определенного момента в прошлом.
Тире авторское, интонационное, оно обозначает противопоставление глагольных форм в тексте: мечтал быть — был вынужден стать. В этом случае первая часть интонационно подчеркнута. Такие конструкции называются параллельными.
В данном случае это выбор автора, но такой знак (без грамматического обоснования) возможен по правилам.  В то же время по грамматическим показателям тире здесь необязательно.

Приветствую, Sharon! Всё красиво, только кажется, что то же нужно раздельно. (В тоже время...)

Спасибо, правило забыла.
